# Objective C equivalent to javascripts setTimeout?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, timer

I was wondering whether there is a solution to raise an event once after 30 seconds or every 30 seconds in CocoaTouch ObjectiveC.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are a number of options.

The quickest to use is in [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-performSelector_withObject_afterDelay_):

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

(There are a few others with slight variations.)

If you want more control or to be able to say send this message every thirty seconds you probably need [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Comment: My guess is probably not (GCD is C-level and doesn't "know" about selectors; also this API predates GCD) but it's possible that it does use it under the hood.

Answer (score 49):

The performSelector: family has its limitations. Here is the closest setTimeout equivalent:

```
dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC * 0.5);
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do work in the UI thread here
});
```

**EDIT:**
A couple of projects that provide syntactic sugar and the ability to cancel execution (clearTimeout):

- https://github.com/Spaceman-Labs/Dispatch-Cancel
- https://gist.github.com/zwaldowski/955123

Comment: can you reset the delay/timer if something happens before the delay time expires and have it start over?

Comment: Can you dive in further on the limitations with `performSelector` ?

Comment: @Jacksonkr The number of arguments that can be passed.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at the [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) class:

```
NSTimer *timer;
...
timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(thisMethodGetsFiredOnceEveryThirtySeconds:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
[timer fire];
```

Somewhere else you have the actual method that handles the event:

```
- (void) thisMethodGetsFiredOnceEveryThirtySeconds:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"fired!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]
```

[Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-CHDDAEIA)

You may also want to look at the other `NSTimer` methods