# Is there a setTimeout (like) in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios4, settimeout

Is there a similar setTimeout function in objective-c like in javascript?  I dont want a sleep function.

I want to fire a "message" after a period of time gone by but no locking up the device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C equivalent to javascripts setTimeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431895/objective-c-equivalent-to-javascripts-settimeout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Answer (score 1):

As Calvin points you can use NSTimer class.

As an alternative you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method to schedule method call after specific delay (note that it is not guaranteed that delay will be exactly you specified - it just will be not less than that value)

Answer (score 1):

See NSObject's [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3aafterDelay%3a). You can also use [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) — it's particularly useful for mimicking `setInterval()`. And to execute arbitrary code instead of just sending a message, see Grand Central Dispatch's [dispatch_after](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_after).