# Reload a page within a specific time interval in a iphone application

Tags: iphone

In my application, i fetch data from a website in XML format. And after parsing XML file, in my iphone screen i can show some specific message from the website (that message can be updated at any time or a new message can be post in that website at any time).

So, i want to reload the page within a specific time period to show in my application the updated message.

i.e. My application will be auto refresh in after 10sec and give me the updated message list from the website.

Is it possible ?? 
If, than how it is possible. Please anyone briefly described it with example.

Answer (score 1):

To auto-refresh you can use a meta refresh tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

or some javascript, like

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true)", 10000)
```

If you're using a javascript framework, there may be other, more graceful ways of doing this.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I am talking about iphone app. in Cocoa framework in Objective C. Could you please elaborately describe it. PLease.

Comment: The method I described above is for use in HTML applications. If you are writing a native app (in objective C) then you'll just need to run your query function every 10 seconds or so. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431895/objective-c-equivalent-to-javascripts-settimeout for an equivalent of above.